# Android tabbed activity recycler isn't showing and is causing the top bar to scroll

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have been trying to create a tabbed activity for a simple planner application (appropriate files [here](https://gist.github.com/Cameronlund4/0e248ea3106d247b52f914affda1885c)). I have a RecyclerView inside of a fragment, which is being displayed in a ViewPager that's assigned with the tabs. The issue is, when I use a RecyclerView, the content's don't show and the tabs and action bar scroll up (which can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es2kQ.jpg)). I'm using the default and google-supplied code examples, but to no avail. Also, in my fragment with just text, it doesn't seem to center correctly (seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLqZe.jpg), is it the size of the fragment?)

Basically, to sum it up, how does one correctly use a RecyclerView in a tabbed activity fragment, and how does one get text to properly center (or get the layout to be the right size) inside of a tabbed activity fragment?

EDIT: The source was hyperlinked (in the "here"s) If you can't find those...
- Gist: https://gist.github.com/Cameronlund4/0e248ea3106d247b52f914affda1885c
- Issue with scrolling: https://i.stack.imgur.com/es2kQ.jpg
- Issue with centering: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLqZe.jpg

**More info:** I added debug messages to pretty much every method in the adapters, fragments, and activities. All of the GradeFragment's methods are running fine, however the only method being run inside of the ClassAdapter for this is onAttachedToRecyclerView. I'm 99% sure this is the cause of the non-showing up cards (Because the data is never getting put into the cards then), however I have no idea why this would occur.

Comment: Well, without posting any code I'd not expect much of the help... See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski My bad, forgot to link the text. Adding it in now.

Comment: Remove this from the Toolbar in the activity xml: `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`

Comment: @DanielNugent Thanks, that helps with the tool bar. Any idea why the items aren't showing up in the recyclerview? No errors, no warnings, and it's pretty much exactly copied from an example provided by google.

Comment: You really should put the relevant code in your question instead of github links.  As for your RecyclerView issue, try calling `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after the call to `mAdapter.setClasses(classes);`

Comment: @DanielNugent As it's a combination of about 5 files, I thought that it would be more appropriate to put them in a gist instead of having a massive block of text. As for the setClasses(), it calls notifyDataSetChanged().

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what's going on. In my constructor for the GradeFragment class, I catch an error for a ParseException. Due to my non-android experience, I simply did Exception.printStackTrace() and it never caught my eye as an issue. The thing is, in AndroidStudio, that doesn't show to the default debug window. **Learn from my lesson,** use log when printing errors.